# Fetch object list from GCS bucket in descending order of createTime

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-apis-explorer

I'm using following rest API to fetch object list from bucket hosted at google cloud storage.

`GET /storage/v1/b/<bucket>/o`

The objects in response are ordered by time in ascending order. Since I have too many objects in the bucket I don't want to fetch them all. Instead I want to fetch objects in descending order and with a limit on the number of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the API. You'll have to list all objects.

Alternatively, you could consider using [Cloud Pub/Sub Notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) which lets you get a feed of newly created objects, if that fits your use case.